# Checking if values are equal in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CustomerName     EmailAddress
Aaron            aaron@gmail.com
Christy          aaron@gmail.com
Jason            jason@gmail.com
Eric             eric@gmail.com
Aaron            bob@gmail.com
```

I want to return the values in the table where customerName's are equal and emailaddress are not equal.  So for example this table should return.

```
Aaron            aaron@gmail.com
Aaron            bob@gmail.com
```

I'm new to sql and i'm unsure how to break this up into checkign first that customernames are the same, and then looking at the emailaddresses

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT()`, but what you want is not very clear, it seems to be a `UNION` between two `DISTINCTS` (CustomerName and EmailAddress). More info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accomplish this with a [self-join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/):

```
Select * from tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.customername = b.customername
and a.emailaddress != b.emailaddress
```

Here it is working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75687/1

You mention only wanting one result. Then you would just modify the above like:

```
Select Distinct(a.customername) from tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.customername = b.customername
and a.emailaddress != b.emailaddress
```

Working version of this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75687/3

Comment: Of course you are, otherwise how would you know what the duplicate data is?

Comment: Updated with alternate distinct result.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `customername` and then count how namy unique emails you have

```
select customername
from your_table
group by customername
having count(distinct emailaddress) > 1
```

If you want also the email in your result you can do

```
select customername, emailaddress
from your_table
where customername in
(
    select customername 
    from your_table
    group by customername
    having count(distinct emailaddress) > 1
)
```